# Jquery .on event with selector for dynamically loaded elements with selectors

Tags: jquery

I am modifying the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js that is packaged with asp.net mvc 3 to allow dynamically loaded forms to work.

Old:

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    /*code here */
});
```

My code:

```
$("body").on("submit","form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    /*code here */
});
```

For mine, the event is never fired at all. Is it that the second parameter (selector) has to be directly under `body`? I am not sure what exactly to do to get the same functionality to work with dynamically loaded forms.

Comment: Does it work for you with `live`?

Comment: Yeah, why doesn't `live` work?

Comment: when I use live, it doesn't work with dynamically loaded elements, but when I changed the code, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: This fiddle appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/A5BWp/1/
So I can only assume your error is in your html. Can you post that?
edit: `live()` is doing the same fundamental thing, so if it's not working, that's more evidence of a problem with your html...

Comment: live should work fine with dynamically loaded elements, on is the better way to do this now - it replaces live, and is more useful and faster.

Comment: I have no idea why it behaved like this, but after I reverted to the old `live`, it works, but I still cant get the `on` to work for anything. I'll just use `live`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this:

```
$(document).on("submit","form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
/*code here */
});
```

I myself have had instances where sometimes it doesn't work with "body", but does with document.

Comment: why? do you have `<form>` in the `<head>` **?!**

Comment: In my own experience some events don't work if you use just body.